# Where do I place a maya script if I'm gonna run it without launching maya?

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya, leap-motion

Is it possible to run a Maya Python script from outside Maya and see the result in Maya simultaneously?

If not, how to make my leap motion code work in Maya without terminating after closing the text input pop-up window?

I'm working on a project where I manipulate Maya Objects using a Leap Motion Device and Maya keeps asking me for a text Input and once I close it, it terminates leap motion code.

Any help?

You can find my code below:

```
    from os.path import join
    import maya.standalone; maya.standalone.initialize()
    import maya.cmds as cmds
    import Leap, sys, thread, time
    from Leap import CircleGesture, KeyTapGesture, ScreenTapGesture, SwipeGesture




class LeapMotionListener(Leap.Listener) :
    # Naming the fingers and bones and states
    finger_names = ['Thumb', 'Index', 'Middle', 'Ring', 'Pinky']
    bone_names = ['Metacarpal', 'Proximal', 'Intermediate', 'Distal']
    state_names = ['STATE_INVALID', 'STATE_START', 'STATE_UPDATE', 'STATE_END']

    # Determines what happens when Initialized
    def on_init(self, controller):
        print("Initialized")
    # Determines what happens when connected
    def on_connect(self, controller):
        print ("Motion Sensor Connected!")

        controller.enable_gesture(Leap.Gesture.TYPE_CIRCLE);
        controller.enable_gesture(Leap.Gesture.TYPE_KEY_TAP);
        controller.enable_gesture(Leap.Gesture.TYPE_SCREEN_TAP);
        controller.enable_gesture(Leap.Gesture.TYPE_SWIPE);

    def on_disconnect(self, controller):
        print("Motion Sensor Disconnected")

    def on_exit(self, controller):
        print("Exited")

    def on_frame(self, controller):
        frame = controller.frame()

        for gesture in frame.gestures():
            if gesture.type is Leap.Gesture.TYPE_CIRCLE:
                circle = CircleGesture(gesture)

                if circle.pointable.direction.angle_to(circle.normal) <= Leap.PI/2: #If Clockwise
                    clockwiseness = "clockwise"
                else:
                    clockwiseness = "counter-clockwise"

                swept_angle = 0
                if circle.state != Leap.Gesture.STATE_START:
                    #We create a new Circle gesture, with the id of the gesture created by the previous frame
                    previous = CircleGesture(controller.frame(1).gesture(circle.id))
                    #We get the angle rotated from the previous frame till the current one
                    swept_angle = (circle.progress - previous.progress) * 2 * Leap.PI

                print "ID: " + str(circle.id) + ", progress: " + str(circle.progress) + ", Radius (mm): " + str(circle.radius) \
                + ", Swept Angle: " + str(swept_angle * Leap.RAD_TO_DEG) + ", Direction: " + clockwiseness

                #Create a polyCube when I do a circle gesture
                result = cmds.polyCube(w = 9, h = 9 , d = 9, name ='myCube#')


def main():
    listener = LeapMotionListener()
    controller = Leap.Controller()

    controller.add_listener(listener)

    print("Press Enter to quit.")

    try:
        sys.stdin.readline()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        controller.remove_listener(listener)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking maya for the text box in the lines

`try:
        sys.stdin.readline()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        controller.remove_listener(listener)`

But the input will block access to the scene.  You should probably add a gesture to trigger the disconnection instead, that way you won't have anything to worry about from the text box.  Without the SDK it's not easy to test, but something like this:

```
class LeapMotionListener(Leap.Listener) :

    #... other code here

    def on_frame(self, controller):
        frame = controller.frame()

        for gesture in frame.gestures():
            #.... other code here....
            if gesture.type is Leap.Gesture.TYPE_SWIPE:
                controller.remove_listener(this)


listener = LeapMotionListener()
controller = Leap.Controller()

controller.add_listener(listener)
```

Comment: That gets rid of the textbox, but still, It runs for once and terminates, how can I make it continuossly reading input from the leap motion without the try clause? or an infinite loop which makes Maya freeze once I run it inside of it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API for Leap.  Does the `Controller` class have a main loop that can be set to run forever? or is there a signal you need to pass to the controller to tell it to continue or to stop?

Comment: it does not, the sample code depends on waiting for the user to press enter (reading a line) to interrupt the code and removes the listener from the class and terminate it.
So I am looking for a way other than this to let the code run and the listener keeps listening to the leap motion frames.